# Get a value from a Promise Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, es6-promise

One of function inside a typescript class returns a `Promise<string>`. How do I unwrap/yield the value inside that promise.

```
functionA(): Promise<string> {
   // api call returns Promise<string>
}

functionB(): string {
   return this.functionA() // how to unwrap the value inside this  promise
}
```

Comment: You can't directly get a value out of a promise.  You use a `.then()` handler on the promise to get access to the value.

Comment: it's simply not possible, you can't play with the stuff you've bought before it has been delivered, not even if you have a delivery notification; or the guy at the store promised you that the package is on its way. Promises manage time, the String you want simply ain't there yet, and there's no way to tell when it will be, except of `then()`. `functionB()` has to return a Promise, there's no way around that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> How do I unwrap/yield the value inside that promise

You can do it with `async`/`await`.Don't be fooled into thinking that you just went from async to sync, async await it is just a wrapper around `.then`.

```
functionA(): Promise<string> {
   // api call returns Promise<string>
}

async functionB(): Promise<string> {
   const value = await this.functionA() // how to unwrap the value inside this  promise
   return value;
}
```

## Further

- [TypeScript Deep Dive docs](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/future-javascript/async-await#async-await-support-in-typescript)

Comment: * The link no more available and redirects to home page. It also feels very promotional (although, author might have good intent at heart). Request the admins to look into it.

Comment: I do link to docs I've written but I am careful to do it under `more` / `further` section. To decrease the promotional feel I've added to the answer body 

Comment: I've also had the same problem by doing as is suggested above but then calling functionB in a synchronous way. Make sure it's still async() => {  value = await functionB() } and so on for any other function when you need the result of the promise.

Comment: Great answer. This helped me understand async/await in TypeScript.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
functionB(): string {
   return this.functionA().then(value => ... );
}
```

Comment: still returns a `Promise<string>`

Comment: @Rjk in the `then` function the `value` is the `string`

Comment: yes, I understand that. I need to return the `string`, instead of `Promise<string>`.

Comment: @Rjk you can't return string.You must return promise and in the calling function assign the value in the `then` to your variable

Comment: `functionA` is asynchronous and therefore there's no chance you will be able to return a single `string` value from it via `functionB`. You might get by by passing a `callback` to `functionB`, but that would defeat the purpose of having the `functionB` in between. @SurenSrapyan's answer is correct and you should do further handling of the `string` within `.then()`.

Comment: @SurenSrapyan I downvoted this answer because you didn't answer the Rjk's question; you answered a different question, then in your comments told Rjk that the original question was wrong.

Comment: This did not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

My working code snippet(to switch to a window containing url string)::

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
                    var length = handles.length;
                    console.log("count of windows::"+length);
                    for (var index=0;index<length;index++) {
                        var newTab = handles[index];
                        browser.switchTo().window(newTab).then(function () {
                            browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(value => {
                                console.log("Printing current url::"+value);
                                if(value.includes("limits")) {
                                    console.log("found limits");
                                }
                            })
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: How does this solve the OP's problem? I think they wanted to fetch values inside a promise typescript and not switch to windows?