# How to get result of promise from angular service with Ionic storage, instead of Promise<any> in response

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, es6-promise, ionic-storage

I'm using `Ionic Storage` for local storage purpose.
To work with storage I've created `service`, where I've getter and setter storage methods.

I want to check on load of application that, if any value is available on storage or not, if value is not available in storage than only want to make actual data call and will set to storage, but next time on wards want to read from storage rather than making actual get call for data.

Now problem is when my component gets load, I'm calling service's `storage.get` method which takes time and because of that component's property is not getting seted with actual storage's correct value.

Also, method used to return string value form service is not allowing to write method without final return statement as mentioned in code below ***[right now I've added two return statement from Promise, which doesn't seems correct design to me, but without it i'm getting compilation error]***, and both return statements gets executed at different interval of time due to time taken by Promise to get response from storage, which yields overtiring of actual response from storage.

I'm not sure how to manage such scenario from promise, as Ionic storage by default returns Promise.

```
 getDefaultLanguage(): string {

     this.storage.get('defaultLanguage').then((res) => {
       return this.defaultLanguage = res || 'en';
     });
     return this.defaultLanguage;
   }
```

Please let me know how I can hold execution in component until I get response from above service call with Promise, so core component's logic can work properly, also wanted correct way to implement service layer where I want result as `string` from Promise instead of `promise<any>`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Nenroz and @mwilson for both of your answers.

It helps me understands how Promise actually works, I was rather looking for single service method which directly returns me string value from Promise and also wanted to wait for further code execution until than.

As, front-end framework react to change itself, so instead of actual ask for this question to wait till getting value from Promise,
I'd find a way to manage to hold UI until Promise get resolves as below. (without awaiting further code execution)

added method `InitStorage()` in `app.component.ts`'s `constructor`

```
 InitStorage() {
     const defLanguage = this.storageService.getDefaultLanguage();
 }
```

`StorageService.ts`'s method as below to return `Promise<string>`

```
 getDefaultLanguage(): Promise<string> {
     return this.storage.get('defaultLanguage');
 }
```

Now to wait till getting value from above method and stop further code execution until promise gets resolved, added its implementation in `ngOnInit` in `page.ts`

```
 ngOnInit() {
      this.defaultLanguage = this.storageService.defaultLanguage;
 }
```

and added its value in `page.html` file, so once value is available in variable html can refreshed/set by framework, previously I was not able to bind its value in HTML `(previously Value was getting sated after Page was getting loaded, and UI was not getting updated)`

```
 <ion-radio-group [value]="defaultLanguage" />
```

I'm not sure if this correct architecture of `service` and `Promise` in `Angular`, but this is how I managed to get `Storage` value in `service` and able to update UI with correct storage value when sated in variable.

Looking forward to any further suggestion for architectural improvement and thanks for all valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to convert it to a promise:

```js
getDefaultLanguage(): Promise <string> {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    this.storage.get('defaultLanguage').then((res) => {
      resolve(res || 'en');
    });
  });
}
```

The reason why your current method doesn't work is because `this.storage.get` is asynchronous. It will not complete in time for `return this.defaultLanguage` to work. Wrapping your `get` call in another `Promise` is one way to do it.

Comment: Yes, `storage.get` is `async` and will return `Promise<any>`, so my original question is how I can get response as `string` from `Promise<>,` can you please show how I can wrap get call into another method to get `string` result instead of `Promise`?
I'm looking for single service method which yields direct `string` output instead of `promise`, i'm not sure how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async` to wait for the promise to be resolved:

```
async getDefaultLanguage(): Promise<string> {
    const res = await this.storage.get('defaultLanguage');
    this.defaultLanguage = res || 'en';

    return this.defaultLanguage;
}
```

Just keep in mind that with this solution `getDefaultLanguage` must now be called asynchronously

Comment: If you can read question one more time what I'm looking for is, how I can get response as `string` instead of `Promise<>,` I'm looking for single service method which yields direct `string` output instead of `promise`, i'm not sure how to achieve it. If i call `async` method than I'm not sure If i can make return out of it.

Comment: I don't think there is a workaround here, check this similare question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39032333/get-a-value-inside-a-promise-typescript